# Angular: problem two components data binding

Tags: angular

I have a problem with data binding two components. The first one sends the data as an object and the second one iterates over it and outputs the data in inputs (value is the value of every element). I want to change the values of the object in the first component when the values of the inputs changes.

multilingual-admin.component.html

```
<form >
  <app-iteration-multilingual *ngIf="test" [(array)] = 'test'></app-iteration-multilingual>
</form>
```

iteration-multilingual.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array | keyvalue"  >
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width"  *ngIf="type(item.value) != 'object'" style="margin-left: 500px; padding-bottom: 50px;" >
  <input matInput placeholder="{{item.key}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value"  name=" " >

</mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <app-iteration-multilingual  style="margin-left: 20px;"  [(array)] = 'item.value' *ngIf="type(item.value) == 'object'"></app-iteration-multilingual>
</ng-container >
```

[Link to stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgvtum)

Comment: Please show some relevant code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgvtum

Comment: here are the two folders

Comment: @MartinKostadinov when you say ` values of the object in the first component` .. your "`first`" component means which one ? Please be more specific. Do you want to monitor changes in `IterationMultilingualComponent` ??

Comment: I want when one of the input value changes the MultilingualAdmin "tes" object same value changes too

Comment: @MartinKostadinov Did my answer work ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your shared code, I think you need to check value change in `IterationMultilingualComponent`.

You need to implement `OnChanges`

```
export class IterationMultilingualComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('array') array: Array<any>;

  constructor() {
  }


  ngOnInit() {


  }
  ngOnChanges(data: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('Input value changed');
    console.log(this.array)
    console.log(data['array'].currentValue);
    console.log(data['array'].previousValue);
  }

  console() {
    console.log(this.array);
  }
  type(item: any) {
    return typeof item;
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.array);
  }

}
```

---

**Please try not to rename variable with name such as `array`. Try to keep more meaningful names and not something which might sound similar to reserve keywords**